# jquery image flip-rotation effect

Tags: jquery, image, plugins

is there any jquery plugin known which could rotate an image around the imagecenter-x axis, like flipping it around?

thnx!

Comment: Animated rotation or one-time on load rotation?

Answer (score 2):

This one!
https://github.com/heygrady/transform/wiki/

Comment: looks interesting, thanx!  ut how could I turn an image , like folding it in half and then flipping the upper part around, having the next image under it...

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm having a difficult time visualizing what you're describing. Maybe a drawing or a site which has an example of something similar would help me understand.

Comment: think of these old adress-boxes ([link](http://www.onlinehandel-as24.de/images/product_images/popup_images/1824_3.jpg)) or these pre-digital clocks ([link](http://www.ladidah.com.au/range/images/flip-clock-grey.jpg))

Comment: or this one: [link](http://www.throttlelauncher.com/custom/widgets/img/RyomaHino-Hero%20FlipCLock%20animated%20%28fixed%29-04.png)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/flip-an-image/ + jquery ability to perform animation: You can animate width of image. When width equals to 0 then flip image and animate width from 0 to orginal width.

Comment: hey, thanx for the tip! but I thought more on something like this: [link](http://keith-wood.name/imageCube.html) but more kind of turn down, when you change the calender page...